# Laravel check for old password, when change new password

Tags: php, laravel

I want check if user pass new_password input as current password, I want to redirect with message: `Your current password can't be with new password`. How I can check this? I want do system change password user, but I want denied old passwords pass. How I can do ?

```
if (!(Hash::check($request->old_password, Auth::user()->password))) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => ['Your current password can't be with new password']], 400);
}
```

Code is not working.
Do I need write old passwords to database?

Comment: Then you need to store the old password hashes in a separate table matched with the user ID. On password change attempt, check through that table to match

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

/*
* Validate all input fields
*/
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'required',
    'new_password' => 'confirmed|max:8|different:password',
]);

if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) { 
   $user->fill([
    'password' => Hash::make($request->new_password)
    ])->save();

   $request->session()->flash('success', 'Password changed');
    return redirect()->route('your.route');

} else {
    $request->session()->flash('error', 'Password does not match');
    return redirect()->route('your.route');
}
```

Comment: How come this is an answer? you can not directly put the `'password' => Auth::user()->password,` code in `validate()` function. it will throw an error..

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use the Hash::check function in a custom rule or request?

Comment: I've voted because of the Hash::check() method. I didn't know about it. but `$user->fill(['password'])` is definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 14):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'old_password' => [
        'required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password)) {
                $fail('Old Password didn\'t match');
            }
        },
    ],
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

> **You may need to include the following libraries in your controller.**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Answer (score 8):

- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074932/3692788) is fine. But it's better to have the `Hash::check` as an additional validation rule, so we have all of the error messages together, as suggested by [Jonson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582172/jonson)'s answer.
- However, since our custom validation is part of the rules array, we don't need to use `Validator::make`.

This is a solution based on both answers:

```
$user = auth()->user();
        
$validated = $request->validate([
    'current_password' => [
        'required',
        
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($user) {
            if (!Hash::check($value, $user->password)) {
                $fail('Your password was not updated, since the provided current password does not match.');
            }
        }
    ],
    'new_password' => [
        'required', 'min:6', 'confirmed', 'different:current_password'
    ]
]);

$user->fill([
    'password' => Hash::make($validated['new_password'])
])->save();

$request->session()->flash('notification', 'Your password has been updated successfully.');

return back();
```

Answer (score 3):

for Laravel 8 use can use `current_password`

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'current_password' => ['required','current_password']
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-current-password

Comment: it's also works for laravel 9. thanks @Salehi

Answer (score 2):

Check your old password field against the session password and return the error followed by the required validation.

```
if (!Hash::check($request['old_password'], Auth::user()->password)) {
      return response()->json(['error' => ['The old password does not match our records.'] ]);
 }
```

You also need to include the following libraries in your controller.

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Comment: This is perfect answer for those, who are working with API. Just a couple corrections: instead or `error` should be returned `errors` to work with form validation properly. AND response has to be 422. So my solution is `if (!Hash::check($request['old_password'], $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => ['old_password' => 'The old password does not match our records.']], 422);
        }` where `$user` is already obtained with aAuth mechanism

Answer (score -7):

You can do like this

```
if ( Hash::make($request->new_password) == Auth::user()->password) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ['Your current password can't be with new password']], 400);
    }
```

Comment: It won't work, as the hash generated will always be different from the old one.