# How to check validation for old password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to check if the user request for a new password then he have to enter his old password. But as in my database the password save as hash password I can't verify the old and new password. So far I tried

```
'password' => 'nullable|confirmed|min:6',
            'old' => 'required_with:password|same:'.$user->password,
```

But as I say for the hash password it doesn't work. please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel check for old password, when change new password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074815/laravel-check-for-old-password-when-change-new-password)

Comment: Could you please try to rephrase the question to clarify the problem, it the user have requested a new password the reason could be he doesn't remember the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this with validation. I have done it like the way below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

if (!(Hash::check($request->current-password, Auth::user()->password))) {
    return redirect()->back()->with("error","your current password does not match with the password you provided. please try again.");
}
```

In this case `$request->current-password` is the old password provided by the user. And I am checking it with the user password using `Hash`